# super priviliege not set for master user in aws rds mysql

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

I have created an AWS RDS instance, I have created my master user with master password, and it is working/connecting fine.

But when I am going to create a function on that instance, it shows me the following error:

```
ERROR 1418: This function has none of DETERMINISTIC, NO SQL, 
or READS SQL DATA in its declaration and binary logging is enabled  
(you might want to use the less safe log_bin_trust_function_creator variable).
```

In my instance the variable `log_bin_trust_function_creators` shows `OFF`, and if I try to change the variable using `SET GLOBAL log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1;`, it gives me another error `"Error Code: 1227. Access denied; you need (at least one of) the SUPER privilege(s) for this operation"`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A better way is to apply your own parameter group, with log_bin_trust_function_creators set to true. (its false by default)

Answer (score 2):

Set log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1 for Parameter group of the RDS instance.

**Note: Default Parameter-Group is not editable. Create a new Parameter-Group and assign it to the RDS instance by modifying it from UI (AWS Admin Console) OR maybe using commands**

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`DB_USERNAME_HERE`@`%` FUNCTION `GetDistance`(coordinate1 VARCHAR(120), coordinate2 VARCHAR(120)) RETURNS decimal(12,8)
READS SQL DATA
BEGIN
   DECLARE distance DECIMAL(12,8);
   /*Business logic goes here for the function*/
   RETURN distance;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

Here, you have to replace **DB_USERNAME_HERE** with you RDS database username and function names according to you need.

**Important thing is: `` DEFINER=`DB_USERNAME_HERE`@`%` ``**

This was the problem I was facing after setting log_bin_trust_function_creators = 1 in parameter group. And it worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

This happens when you try to create a procedure/function/view with a `DEFINER` that is not the current user.

To solve this remove or update the `DEFINER` clause.

Comment: That would be awesome if it worked, but still no joy with DEFINER = CURRENT_USER.